# How to add more countries or unblock blocked roads in Euro Truck Simulator 2?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I'm playing Euro Truck Simulator 2 1.17.1 (64 bit). I have explored almost all the roads that are available. While driving I can see some roads are blocked. Is there any way to unblock the blocked roads?

Also, is it possible to add more countries? If yes, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to add more roads to the game is by buying the expansion DLCs. (And mods, as pointed out by TZHX, but I know nothing more about those.)
At the moment, there are 2:

- Going East (adds Poland, Czech Republic, Slovakia and Hungary)
- Scandinavia (adds Denmark and parts of Sweden and Norway)

There is no **in-game way** to unlock any roads. Those are simply areas that weren't made, so there propably isn't anything beyond a little fake stretch of road anyways.

Comment: There's also quite a few mods around, of varying quality, that add new areas.